# Are the expressions "zum Besuch" or "zu Besuch" interchangeable

Tags: idiom

I have heard both these used when someone is visiting - can someone explain if there is a difference or can both be used interchangeably?

Comment: *Zum Besuch* is short for *zu **dem** Besuch*, which indicates dative case. It cannot be used interchangeably to *zu Besuch*, which indicates accusative case. When to use which depends on grammar in the sentence where it is used.

Comment: *Zu Besuch* isn't accusative, it's dative, but without the article. Dative is the only case one can use with "zu". Also consider "zu Tische sitzen", where the (old-fashioned) dative-e indicates dative.

Comment: @Janka *zu Besuch* is no accusative as RHa rightly pointed out. *zu* can only take the dative.

Answer (score 8):

Generally speaking, *zu Besuch* is an idiomatic expression mening "visiting". Based on a brief corpus research, its use seems to be essentially confined to the phrases *zu Besuch sein*, *zu Besuch kommen*, and *(jmdn.) zu Besuch haben*.

> (1) *Wohnst du hier? -- Nein, ich bin (hier) zu Besuch.*
>
> (2) *Mein Bruder kam zu Besuch.*
>
> (3) *Ich konnte nicht auf die Feier kommen, weil ich meine Eltern zu Besuch hatte.*

<sub>[This is not surprising. Such a drop of the article is a frequent feature of *Funktionsverbgefüge* (FVGs). Only a very small subset of semantically weak verbs - *Funktionsverben* - can be used in such (here: prepositional) FVGs. In essence, what happens is that these verbs are used in a way where they "lose" some of their ordinary meaning (desemanticization) and the resulting semantic void is then filled with a prepositional phrase. E.g.: *in Umlauf bringen; in Betrieb nehmen.* The three verbs above - *sein/kommen/haben* - just happen to be the only *Funktionsverben* (as far as I can tell) that make sense with *zu Besuch*. Note that FVGs are idiomatic; you can't just make up new ones.]</sub>

You cannot use *zu Besuch* in other contexts. Hence it's only:

> (4) *jmdn. zum Besuch einladen/bitten/laden; eine Gelegenheit zum Besuch ergreifen/wahrnehmen; sich zum Besuch ankündigen/ansagen/anmelden; zum Besuch Blumen (mit)bringen; etw. berechtigt zum Besuch; etw. steht zum Besuch offen*

You also can no longer use *zu Besuch* with *sein/kommen/haben* once you "break up" the FVG, such as by adding arbitrary attributes to the noun. Hence:
*Er kam zum Besuch der Mutter. Er kam zum alljährlichen Besuch.* (Please refer to your favorite comprehensive grammar of German for details.)

<sub>[So are they at least sometimes interchangeable? Well, at least in theory I don't think anything prevents you from using *zum Besuch* (outside an FVG) with *sein/kommen/haben* in such a way that the *zu Besuch* FVG would still be intact. As far as I can see, this clearly spells trouble only with *sein* (which is by far the weakest verb of the three, semantically speaking), at least unless specified. However, compare: *<sup>?</sup>Mein Bruder kam zum Besuch.* There is quite some semantic value in *kommen*. Compare: *Mein Bruder kam zum Abendessen/zur Taufe/zur Party.*]</sub>

My practical advice would be to use *zu Besuch* with *sein/kommen/haben* unless it's not possible (especially because you have added an attribute to *Besuch*). It sounds rounder, even if occassionally *zum Besuch* might be an option. Use *zum Besuch* otherwise.